# Decoupling DomainDbContext from IdentityDbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I'm building an airline manager which has it's own database for flight, airlines, countries, users etc..

Now I've come to the part I want to add Authentication into the app and I realized that ASP.NET Core Identity derives from a special kind of DbContext and I'm not sure if it's OK to add domain DBSets to the IdentityDbContext (basically make one Db that involves both Identity and the domain tables).

I didn't find any "best practices" for this scenario, should one use a different DB for authentication apart from the domain DB? If so, my users table has foreign keys to different tables (tickets to connect to flights, user descriptions) - separating the users from the DB will break everything.

I'd appreciate your kind opinion and I hope this thread will educate other beginners on best course of action when designing (identity) authenticated solutions.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
Just for clarification, when I say two different contexts, I also mean two separate databases.

Comment: If you have different databases for Identity and other Domain objects then you need to have two different Contexts.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Alright that means I need to port the Users from the DomainDbContext into the IdentityDbContext. Removing Users will result in breaking the users to flights many to many relationship. How would one architect this so I don't break. Is there a way to project at least the IDs from Identity into a Users table to hold as reference? (Kind of 1:1 from different databases)

Answer (score 1):

Airline manager seems not a small project and could potentially expand eventually. Having said that, How about the approach not just separating the databases but separating the projects / services. Good for maintenance tho and more flexible. IdentityServer4, look on its github repo to begin with. https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4 - you should be able to see samples here too on how your app/s integrates to its services.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I used only one database with the identity tables provided by aspnetcoreidentity and the proprietary tables of the project, to connect a user to my tables I used the same AspNetUserId.
I am using a dbcontext for the security tables and a dbcontext for the other tables.

```
services.AddDbContext<PaginaInnovitaliaEditorEngineDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(
        Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(
        Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Comment: As I said, my current "User" table has FKs to the User's Description (1 : 1) and also to a Tickets table (1 : many) . If I detach the user onto another Database - I'm breaking everything. How would one approach this?

Comment: you have to keep everything in a single database, you can use two context if you want to manage the tables, but at this point use a single context and a single database